# android camera2 orientation for emulator camera wrong

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am following a tutorial currently and trying to set up android camera 2. This is the code for it.

MainActivity:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT = 0;
private Button btnCapture;
private TextureView mTextureView;
private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
        setUpCamera(i,i1);
        connectCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

    }
};
private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
private  HandlerThread mBackgroundHandlerThread;
private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
private static SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0,0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90,90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180,180);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270,270);
}
private Size mPreviewSize;
private CaptureRequest.Builder mCaptureRequestBuilder;

private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraDeviceStateCallBack = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }
};
private String mCameraId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextureView = findViewById(R.id.textureView);
}




@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    startBackgroundThread();

    if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
        setUpCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(),mTextureView.getHeight());
        connectCamera();
    } else {
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextListener);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
        if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Application will not run without camera services ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void closeCamera() {
    if (mCameraDevice != null) {
        mCameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }
}


private void startBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("camera2VideoImage");
    mBackgroundHandlerThread.start();

    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundHandlerThread.getLooper());
}

private void stopBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundHandlerThread.quitSafely();
    try {
        mBackgroundHandlerThread.join();
        mBackgroundHandlerThread = null;
        mBackgroundHandler = null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static int sensorToDeviceRotation(CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics, int deviceOrientation) {
    int sensorOrientation = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
    deviceOrientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(deviceOrientation);
    return ((sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360);

}


private void setUpCamera(int width, int height) {
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        for (String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            if (cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) ==
                    CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                continue;
            }
            StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

            int deviceOrientation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            int totalRotation = sensorToDeviceRotation(cameraCharacteristics,deviceOrientation);
            boolean swapRotation = totalRotation == 90 || totalRotation == 270;
            int rotatedWidth = width;
            int rotatedHeight = height;
            if (swapRotation) {
                rotatedWidth = height;
                rotatedHeight = width;
            }
            mPreviewSize = chooseOptimaSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), rotatedWidth ,
                    rotatedHeight);
            mCameraId = cameraId;
            return;
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void connectCamera() {
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceStateCallBack, mBackgroundHandler);
            } else {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            "Video app requires access to camera"
                            ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT);
            }
        } else {
            cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceStateCallBack, mBackgroundHandler);
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void startPreview() {
    SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
    surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(),mPreviewSize.getHeight());
    Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
    try {
        mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                try {
                    cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),
                            null, mBackgroundHandler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unable to setup preview",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } , null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



private static class CompareSizeByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
        return Long.signum((long)lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() /
                (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
    }
}

private static Size chooseOptimaSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height) {
    List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();
    for (Size option : choices) {
        if (option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * height / width &&
                option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
            bigEnough.add(option);
        }
    }
    if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizeByArea());
    } else {
        return choices[0];
    }

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    closeCamera();
    super.onPause();
    stopBackgroundThread();
    }
}
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT = 0;
private Button btnCapture;
private TextureView mTextureView;
private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
        setUpCamera(i,i1);
        connectCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

    }
};
private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
private  HandlerThread mBackgroundHandlerThread;
private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
private static SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0,0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90,90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180,180);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270,270);
}
private Size mPreviewSize;
private CaptureRequest.Builder mCaptureRequestBuilder;

private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraDeviceStateCallBack = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }
};
private String mCameraId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextureView = findViewById(R.id.textureView);
}




@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    startBackgroundThread();

    if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
        setUpCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(),mTextureView.getHeight());
        connectCamera();
    } else {
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextListener);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
        if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Application will not run without camera services ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void closeCamera() {
    if (mCameraDevice != null) {
        mCameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }
}


private void startBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("camera2VideoImage");
    mBackgroundHandlerThread.start();

    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundHandlerThread.getLooper());
}

private void stopBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundHandlerThread.quitSafely();
    try {
        mBackgroundHandlerThread.join();
        mBackgroundHandlerThread = null;
        mBackgroundHandler = null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static int sensorToDeviceRotation(CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics, int deviceOrientation) {
    int sensorOrientation = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
    deviceOrientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(deviceOrientation);
    return ((sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360);

}


private void setUpCamera(int width, int height) {
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        for (String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            if (cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) ==
                    CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                continue;
            }
            StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

            int deviceOrientation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            int totalRotation = sensorToDeviceRotation(cameraCharacteristics,deviceOrientation);
            boolean swapRotation = totalRotation == 90 || totalRotation == 270;
            int rotatedWidth = width;
            int rotatedHeight = height;
            if (swapRotation) {
                rotatedWidth = height;
                rotatedHeight = width;
            }
            mPreviewSize = chooseOptimaSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), rotatedWidth ,
                    rotatedHeight);
            mCameraId = cameraId;
            return;
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void connectCamera() {
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceStateCallBack, mBackgroundHandler);
            } else {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            "Video app requires access to camera"
                            ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT);
            }
        } else {
            cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceStateCallBack, mBackgroundHandler);
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void startPreview() {
    SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
    surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(),mPreviewSize.getHeight());
    Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
    try {
        mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                try {
                    cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),
                            null, mBackgroundHandler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"unable to setup preview",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } , null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



private static class CompareSizeByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
        return Long.signum((long)lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() /
                (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
    }
}

private static Size chooseOptimaSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height) {
    List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();
    for (Size option : choices) {
        if (option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * height / width &&
                option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
            bigEnough.add(option);
        }
    }
    if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizeByArea());
    } else {
        return choices[0];
    }

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    closeCamera();
    super.onPause();
    stopBackgroundThread();
}
```

}

activity_main xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextureView
   android:id="@+id/textureView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_above="@+id/buttonCapture"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonCapture"
    android:text="CAPTURE"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.androidcamera2api">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CameraActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Currently using SDK 27.

I currently do not have a real android phone to test so i am using an emulator. 
However, when i launch my app even though the phone is in portrait mode the camera becomes landscape. It looks something like this.

[image]

i thought the code that handled this was in the setUpCamera method where i swapped the width and height if the orientation is 90 or 270? Appreciate the help !

Comment: Please post the complete code, including the java imports in MainActivity.java, content of activity_main.xml, and your min, target and compile SDK versions.

Comment: @deLock i posted my whole code here some imports were unused.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code on Google Pixel 2 (Android 8.1 -- same API as yours) and the picture is **shown correctly** -- the head is at the top, unlike in the screenshot you posted.

So I conclude it's a bug in the emulator you're using.

I would only make this change to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

That way you will get the same behavior that e.g. Samsung and Google use for their Camera apps on their flagship phones. The orientation of the UI layout is locked (only the icon pictures rotate if you rotate the device to landscape, but the UI layout does not rotate).